# what does | or || mean in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What does | or || mean in Swift? I have come across them in some Swift tutorials.

Comment: see as reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bitwise `OR` operator, as documented in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise-OR ( | ) together the constants that represent the particular aspects you want.Apple regularly use bit masks for allowing multiple values to be stored in a single variable. 
for example:**autoresizingMask**

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

for more details

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301
http://swinden.com/bitwise/

Answer (score 0):

This is Bitwise OR operation, but to enter your switch case your `contactMask` has to be exactly the same that `BodyType.boundary.rawValue | BodyType.sensorUp.rawValue`

The condition is the same that : `if contactMask & BodyType.boundary.rawValue && contactMask & BodyType.sensorUp.rawValue`