# What does & (single ampersand), and | (single pipe) operator do in comparison operation?

Tags: swift

In a statement like:

```
if (valueA & valueB) != 99 {

    print("they don't equal 99")

}
```

What does the `&` operator do? I thought it would mean if valueA and valueB both don't equal 99 execute the block.

And then what does the `|` do in this statement:

```
if valueA != (99 | 0) {

    print("it doesn't equal 99")

}
```

I thought it would mean if valueA doesn't equal 99 OR 0 execute the block. However neither of my assumptions seem to be correct.

The correct way to write the above statement is:

```
if valueA != 99 && valueB != 99 {

    print("it doesn't equal 99")

}
```

It seems logical that the first if-statement proposed would be a very succinct way to write that as it shortens the code written and is still, if not more, explicit.

Comment: It might be a tangent but it is certainly not a duplicate to the post referenced. That post talks about bitwise operators but the question is talking specifically about unsigned character arrays. And nowhere in the question or the answer is `|` ever mentioned.

Comment: looks like you are looking for && and | |

Comment: How about this one: [what does | or || mean in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579754/what-does-or-mean-in-swift/28579790#28579790)

Comment: What he was actually trying to do is `if valueA != 99 && valueB != 99 { ... }`

Comment: No, I know how to do that. The question wasn't how to write it and make it work. But you can't write `(valueA && valueB) != 99`, you'll throw an error.

Comment: of course thats not how you are suppose to code it. it needs to be between two booleans

Comment: @spacemonkey it is clear that you didn't know how to use it. Your question never mentioned && or | |

Comment: @LeoDabus No it is not at all clear, the question was not how to compare multiple values in one statement. The question was if these don't work what are they used for.

Comment: @spacemonkey please clarify the question, even with the latest edits it's still is unclear what you're asking without reading all the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are both [*Bitwise Operators*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html), which let you manipulate the actual data bits.

*The information below was copied as-is from the official documentation:*

### Bitwise AND Operator

The bitwise **AND** operator (`&`) combines the bits of two numbers. It returns a new number whose bits are set to `1` only if the bits were equal to `1` in both input numbers:

[image: AND Operator]

---

### Bitwise OR Operator

The bitwise **OR** operator (`|`) compares the bits of two numbers. The operator returns a new number whose bits are set to `1` if the bits are equal to `1` in either input number:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These operators do [bitwise arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

> A bitwise AND takes two equal-length binary representations and performs the logical AND operation on each pair of the corresponding bits, by multiplying them. Thus, if both bits in the compared position are 1, the bit in the resulting binary representation is 1 (1 × 1 = 1); otherwise, the result is 0 (1 × 0 = 0 and 0 × 0 = 0).
>
> A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 0 if both bits are 0, while otherwise the result is 1.