# '|' operator provide me different type of result

Tags: swift

if i write this way

```
let result = 5 | 4 | 22 

print(result)
```

result is :

> 23

```
let result = 5 | 4 | 22 | 9 

print(result)
```

result is:

> 31

and write this

```
let result = 5 | 4

print(result)
```

result is

> 5

I unable to figure out . how work "|" or  operator  ?

Comment: Search up bitwise operators.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34665536/1226963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bitwise OR Operator**

The bitwise OR operator (|) compares the bits of two numbers. The operator returns a new number whose bits are set to 1 if the bits are equal to 1 in either input number:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Art/bitwiseOR_2x.png))</sub>

n the example below, the values of **someBits** and **moreBits** have different bits set to *1*. The bitwise OR operator combines them to make the number **11111110**, which equals an unsigned decimal of **254**:

```
let someBits: UInt8 = 0b10110010
let moreBits: UInt8 = 0b01011110
let combinedbits = someBits | moreBits  // equals 11111110
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html