# What is this code monitoring? -> `stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc`

Tags: ios

I don't konw what's the mean of the code `type == (stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc)`.Does it monitor the alloc? or dealloc? or other?
Code Source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/gen/stack_logging.c.auto.html

I know what the means of the bitwise OR `|`.But in the library of Tencent named OOMDeteotor (https://github.com/Tencent/OOMDetector). which has the code like this:

```
if (type == (stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc)) {

}else if (type == stack_logging_type_dealloc) {

}else if((type & stack_logging_type_alloc) != 0){

}
```

why in else if xxx, it monitor dealooc again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our purpose let's say `stack_logging_type_dealloc` is `0010b` and `stack_logging_type_alloc` is `0001b`

Let's go one at at time.

```
type == (stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc)
```

This expression is true if `type` has the value `0011b` (`0010b | 0001b`).

```
type == stack_logging_type_dealloc
```

This expression is true if `type` has the value `0010b`.

```
(type & stack_logging_type_alloc) != 0
```

This expression is true if `type` has a value that contains `0001b`. For example, if `type` had the value `1010b`, then the expression would be false. However, if `type` had the value `1011b`, then the expression would be true.

---

From the logical prospective:

```
type == (stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc)
```

If `type` has the flags `stack_logging_type_dealloc` and `stack_logging_type_alloc` set, and **no other flags set**, then true.

```
type == stack_logging_type_dealloc
```

If `type` has the flag `stack_logging_type_dealloc` set, and **no other flags set**, then true.

```
(type & stack_logging_type_alloc) != 0
```

If `type` has the flag `stack_logging_type_alloc` set, then true, no matter what other flags are set in `type`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But which situation the code will monitor both of alloc and dealloc.For our purpose let's say stack_logging_type_dealloc is 0010b and stack_logging_type_alloc is 0001b. Is it about the address offset? I am not sure.@Jeffery Thomas

Comment: @ZhanKail look at the calling function. If `stack_logging_log_stack()` is called like this: `stack_logging_log_stack(stack_logging_type_dealloc|stack_logging_type_alloc, …`.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe operator `|` in Swift is bitwise OR. [More information on bitwise OR operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34665536/1477940)

It means, that it monitors situation with both of them together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have something incomprehension. I have edited the question summary. Can you help me?